# Unzipping a document on a certain date and it appearing on the installation folder with another date

Tags: windows, zip, winrar, unzip

**Windows 10** user here. I don't know how WinZip or other unzipping programs work, but when I unzip a certain folder or document using **WinRAR**, the date of the unzipped contents are the dates they were last modified, but this is a bit annoying as I usually unzip my documents in the Download folder of Windows 10 and they don't stay at top as normal downloaded documents.

Is there anyway you can say to the program to modify the date of the unzipped contents to the date of the unzipping itself?

Comment: I am a long time user of WinZip and to the best of my knowledge and a review of options now, the date of the file will be the original file date, not the date you unzip it.

Comment: Ok, so probably the unzipping process characteristics are analague for all unzipping programs. But I'm hoping for some kind of fix.

Comment: I have 7-Zip on another machine and it works the same as WinZip.

Answer (score 1):

## 1. File time dependencies

The file time depends on Windows on:

1. File system of storage media, i.e. NTFS, FAT32, exFAT, etc.
2. Time zone, daylight saving time
3. Automatic adjustment for daylight saving time
4. Version of Windows

See [Find out if file is older than 4 hours in batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32670346/3074564) on Stack Overflow for a comprehensive description.

## 2. Kind of file times

The system drive with the Windows folder is by default using NTFS as file system.
There are three file times available on NTFS using the [NTFS precision time](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/minwinbase/ns-minwinbase-filetime).

1. The **last modification time** which is the time the file contents was last modified. Archivers like *7-Zip*, *WinRAR* or *WinZIP* store the last modification time of a file (or directory being in real also a file in file system with special attribute directory) on adding a file to an archive and restore the last modification time on extracting a file from an archive.
2. The **creation time** which is the time a file was created in the current directory. This file time has nothing to do with file contents. It is the time a file was created in the current directory which means if a copy of a file is made, the copy gets a new creation time being the current time while the last modification time is not changed. So the copy has a newer creation time than the last modification time. The creation time is usually ignored by archives.
3. The **last access time** which is the time the file was last accessed (opened) by a process. The update of last access time is disabled by default since Windows Vista for performance reasons via `HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\FileSystem\NtfsDisableLastAccessUpdate` with value `1` or since Windows 10 with hexadecimal value `0x80000003`(system managed, last access updates disabled). The last access time is usually ignored by archives.

## 3. File time support by RAR and ZIP archive file formats

The (original) [ZIP file format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zip_(file_format)) supports only storing the last modification time with FAT timestamp (two seconds resolution).

The **RAR 4** and **RAR 5** file formats support storing all three times with FAT timestamp or NTFS precision time.

## 4. File time management by *WinRAR*

*WinRAR* gives a user the full control on which file times are stored in a RAR or ZIP archive (depending on archive file format) on adding a file to an archive and which file times are restored on files extracted from a RAR or ZIP archive file via the switch `-ts`.

Click in *WinRAR* in last main menu **Help** on first menu item **Help topics**, select first tab **Contents**, expand list item **Command line mode**, expand sublist item **Switches** and click on list item **"-ts[m,c,a,p][+,-,1]" - save or restore file time (modification, creation, access, preserve)**. The opened help page explains in full details the possibilities offered by *WinRAR* for archiving file times on adding files/directories to an archive and restoring file times on extracting files/directories from archives.

## 5. Extracting archives with *WinRAR* with current time as last modification time

Files/directories can be extracted from archives with current time as last modification time by selecting one or more archive files in *WinRAR*, clicking in *WinRAR* toolbar on item **Extract to**, selecting the second tab **Advanced** and unchecking on this tab in first group **File time** the option **Set modification time** which is by default checked.

Then the last extracted files/directories in downloads folder are listed at top on viewing the downloads folder with list sorted according to last modification time with newest at top and oldest at bottom.

## 6. Use a specific extraction folder with *WinRAR*

It is possible to configure in *WinRAR* a specific folder as extraction folder to avoid that newly downloaded archive files are extracted into the downloads folder itself with restored last modification time making them more difficult to find in the list of files and directories in downloads folder which should be cleared from time to time in any case. So it is possible to create in the downloads folder or the desktop folder a subfolder like `Newly Extracted` and configure this directory as default extraction folder in *WinRAR*.

After creation of the folder `Newly Extracted`, click in *WinRAR* in last but one main menu **Options** on first menu item **Settings**, select the third tab **Paths**, click on button **Browse** of **Default folder for extracted files** and browse to just created folder `Newly Extracted`. It is recommended to check also **Append archive name to path** and **Remove redundant folders from extraction path**. Click on button **Help** for a description of these settings.

It is of course necessary to move the files and directories extracted into the folder `Newly Extracted` to a more suitable directory after evaluation or processing them after the extraction or delete the subfolders no longer needed after extraction and usage before extracting the next archive files into the folder `Newly Extracted`.

Answer (score 0):

I don’t have WinRAR, but I have WinZip and 7-Zip. 
It appears that, when extracting file(s) from an archive,

- WinZip sets the file’s “Date modified” and “Date created” to the file date
  that’s stored in the archive (e.g., `.zip` file), but
- 7-Zip sets the file’s “Date modified” to the file date
  that’s stored in the archive,
  but sets the file’s “Date created” to the current time.

So this procedure *might* allow you to see recently extracted files
at the top (or bottom) of your Downloads folder:

- Add a “Date created” column to your view of your Downloads folder
  (if it isn’t already there),

    [image: ‘Add columns’ menu]

  and
- sort by “Date created”.

Disclosure: This was verified on Windows 7. 
Your results (on Windows 10) may differ.

Comment: Hi, I tried to implement the procedure you explained, but even if I delete the 'date modified' column and order the files by 'date created', the order of them is assigned first by time period (this week, last month, ...) and only then for each period, it is put in order by 'date created' lol... See the link **https://ibb.co/31XhkTB**, maybe its easier to understand that way what I'm saying (sorry for shady website, but the popular ones now require sign up... its called ImgBB, you can search it up if you are one of those people who dont trust shady links).